# Convert Rashi to Hebrew script

Tags: rashi

Is there any software that can convert Rashi script to Hebrew script?  For the purpose of making studying easier.

Example:   When I run into Rashi script online, I would copy and paste it into this software to see it in Hebrew script.   Or I scan a book and use OCR on it, but then have this software change it into Hebrew script.

I am finding that Rashi script makes studying his writings overwhelmingly hard.

Comment: Isn't it just a font change?

Comment: @DoubleAA OCR images don't always recognize the characters as actual letters. (We found this problem with a Hebrew Books page someone asked about last week.) Otherwise, if they are recognized as characters, I'd have to experiment how well a simple font change will work.

Comment: @DanF - see my answer. if the scan is clear enough, it will work. but if the scan is old or fangled, then it will interpret the characters wrong.

Comment: IMHO, it's worth persevering reading the Rashi script so that you can access material without all the bother of scanning etc..

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - I agree, but that's not what the OP asked.  See this great resource though! http://www.dictionary.co.il/rashi_script.php

Answer (score 5):

If the scan is very clear, you can convert the document to a PDF file and then just copy and paste the text, changing the font from Rashi to block letters. If the scan is old and not clear, or there are ink splotches everywhere, then this will not work accurately.

For example, you can easily copy and paste the Rashi letters in [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas) clearly scanned Shas page, but cannot do so accurately in [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39996&st=&pgnum=332&hilite=) unclear and old scan of Mikraos Gedolos Bereishis.

So in short, as long as the scan is high quality and the document is converted to a PDF file, you can copy and paste the Rashi script freely and the computer will recognize it.

Comment: Yup! I just c & p'd the 1st page to MS Word 2010, and it immediately translated it to a "regular" Hebrew font.

Comment: It was a font change!   Who knew it could be that simple in Word.   Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @DanF I wonder why this question-and-answer proceeded so much more gracefully than mine.

Comment: @Chaim With you're ID being "Chaim", they wanted you to live longer thinking about what the moderators were thinking :-) Seriously, I think your question became a learning "curve" for this one. I can't say for certain. Want to test things out? Create another question similar to your last one and see what happens? I don't like changing fonts. It means that I have to change the "ball" on my typewriter! Too much trouble.

Comment: @WestonKohn - If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. :)